# finding minimum in a linked list in optimal method

Tags: c, algorithm, list, linked-list

I came by this problem where we are asked to store a string and a no. associated with it and we are supposed to remove the minimum no.(and its string) from the list and also remove the no.s(and strings) stored after it.The input is a stream of no.,string pair and an input of -1 means we need to remove the samllest from the list and the pairs above it.Output should be the count of items above the minimum numbered item.
e.g. 2 abcd 
     1 aabb
     3 dbbb
     -1
o/p  1 (since minimum is 1 aabb and there is just one item after it i.e. 3 dbbb;our list now contains just 2 abcd).
another -1 would produce as o/p 0.
I have tried this using linked list but it seems to take more time than expected.I need a better data structure or algorithm for the same.
Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct data
    {
        int no,pos;
        char *st;
        struct data *next;
    }data;
void insert(data *start,int n,char *s);
void minimum(data *start);
int total=0,min=100001,posn=0;//total=total no of nodes,rem=nodes after minimum
data *temp;
int main()
    {
        int N,n;
        data *start;
        start=(data*)malloc(sizeof(data));
        start->pos=0;
        start->no=100002;
        start->next=NULL;
        char c,s[16];
        scanf("%d",&N);
        while(N)
            {
                scanf("%d",&n);
                if(n!=-1)
                    {
                        scanf("%c",&c);
                        scanf("%s",s);
                        total++;
                        posn++;
                        insert(start,n,s);
                    }
                else
                    {
                        printf("%d %s\n",total-(temp->next->pos),temp->next->st);
                        posn=temp->pos;
                        total=temp->pos;
                        temp->next=NULL;
                        minimum(start);
                    }
                N--;
            }
    }
void insert(data *start,int n,char *s)
    {
    while(start->next!=NULL)
        start=start->next;
    if(n<=min)
        {
            temp=start;
            min=n;
        }
    start->next=(data*)malloc(sizeof(data));
    start=start->next;
    start->no=n;
    start->st=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(s)));
    strcpy(start->st,s);
    start->pos=posn;
    start->next=NULL;
    return;
    }
void minimum(data *start)
    {
        min=100001;
        while(start->next!=NULL)
            {
                if(start->next->no<=min)
                    {
                        min=start->next->no;
                        temp=start;
                        start=start->next;
                    }
            }
        return;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's also not clear why the min value starts at 100001 instead of INT_MAX (from `<limits.h>`).  It is also a bad idea to make `min` into a global variable.

Comment: In the start->st=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(s))); instruction you are not leaving room for the \0 character on the strcpy you are performing afterwards.

Comment: It is hard to find the minimum of a set of N values in less than O(N) time unless you know that the values are ordered (e.g. stored in a tree structure or a sorted list) and you can get at the minimum or maximum faster because of that.  Traversing a linked list is an O(N) operation; if you correct your code, it is therefore within a constant factor of being optimal.

Comment: Or why not set `min = start->no` (which is apparently being skipped at the moment, so if the minimum happens to be in the first node, it won't be found).

Comment: Isn't it this question from the ongoing contest (http://www.codechef.com/DEC12/problems/BEX) that are you talking about.Come on !! be fair

Comment: @WayneRooneywell its not exactly the same question..all i need is to get an optimal way of finding minimum from linked list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here are some issues with your code:

1. `start=start->next;` should be done in every iteration and not only when a new min is found.
2. <strike>You are always missing the head of the list, iterate `while(start != NULL)` (and check `start->no` instead of the next node).</strike> (It seems `start` is a dummy variable, if it is indeed the case - you are only missing it - which is perfectly fine).
3. <strike>You are missing a return type for the `minimum()` function, it shouldn't be `void`. If your list contains `int`s, the return type should be `int`, and when you exhaust the loop you should `return min;`. (If you are interested in returning the min string attached, store an extra variable `char* minElement`, modify it when you modify `min`, and return it (`minelement`) when the loop is exhausted.</strike> (Note it is a bad practice to store the answer in a global variable, a better approach is to return it from the function)
4. You should initialize min to `INT_MAX` rather an arbitrary number.

---

Regarding the optimization issue:

If you are interested only in finding the minimum element, a **[heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is a data structure** designed exactly for it! It is simple and very efficeint Data Structure for retrieving minimum.

Also note, if your Data structure does not support deletions, you can cache min in each insertion, something along the lines of this pseudo code:

add to insertion function:

```
if (newValue < min):
   min <- newValue
```

and min is simple as retrieving the cached `min`.

Comment: regarding the return type of minimum(),i dont need to return anything..i am storing the minimum node in temp variable which is glabal(i dont think that has anything to do with optimization)

Comment: @AmanAgarwal: Oh, I see it now. Note however it is a bad practice, a better practice will be to return `temp` instead to store it in a global variable.

Comment: heap won't work in my case since i also need to remove the elements that were inserted after the minimum one.